# boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator directory error: Access is denied

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

I want to get a list of files path, use the boost library, run the program, but the program doesn't return all the addresses for me and this warning is displayed.

> boost :: filesystem :: recursive_directory_iterator directory error: Access is denied

How to skip files without access?

```
path p("D:\\");
recursive_directory_iterator dir(p), end;
for (recursive_directory_iterator i(p); i != dir; ++i)
{
    path cp = (*i);
    cout << cp.string() << endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't know boost, but the standard library `std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator` has an constructor that takes a `std::filesystem::directory_options`, where you can set a `skip_permission_denied` bit. See [`recursive_directory_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator/recursive_directory_iterator) and [`directory_options`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_options)

Comment: Yes it's true, but I want to do it with a boost